# last Saturday in October

Tags: excel, vba

How to develop a VBA macro to determine the last Saturday in October for any given year?        (4)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27696008/4088852). While it isn't the best way to approach it, it will at least get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DateSerial and VBA's own WeekDay with vbSunday to retrieve the last Saturday in any October.

```
Option Explicit

Function lastSatOct(yr As Integer) As Date

    lastSatOct = CDate(DateSerial(yr, 11, 1) - Weekday(DateSerial(yr, 11, 1), vbSunday))

End Function
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6z9q.png)

Comment: You might want to double-check the worksheet formula solution's result for the years *2020, 2021, 2026, 2027*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

```
=EOMONTH(A1,0)-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(A1,0),2)-1
```

Comment: Thanks , unfortunately, it is required only to be determine by VBA code

Comment: @Elia If you required `VBA` so why you accept this answer. Why not other answer by `VBA` coding.

Comment: My apologize, I am very new here and I got confused. Thanks for mentioned this.

Answer (score 1):

## Last Saturday in October

### Function

```
Function LSat10(Year As Long) As Date

    Dim i As Long
    Dim vntDate As Date

    vntDate = DateSerial(Year, 10, 31)

    For i = 0 To 6
        If Weekday(vntDate - i) = 7 Then Exit For
    Next

    LSat10 = vntDate - i

End Function
```

## EDIT (2019-02-12)

As [T.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m) pointed out in the comments, there is a better solution, using the `Weekday` function:

```
Function LSat10(Year As Long) As Date

    Dim vntDate As Date

    vntDate = DateSerial(Year, 10, 31)
    LSat10 = vntDate - (Weekday(vntDate) Mod 7)

End Function
```

Although it is probably the best solution, it is 'tied' to the `firstdayofweek` argument of the `Weekday` function by *default* set to `1` (`vbSunday`) where the 7th day is 'incidentally' Saturday.

To further develop the function for other days and months, the approach in the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612895/last-saturday-in-october/54614136#54614136) of [user11040196](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11040196/user11040196) is much better (regarding the use of the 1st of the next month): the last day of a month can be **28-31**, but the first day can only be **1**.

### Date of a Last Day of a Month

This approach I used in the development of the following function which calculates the last date of any (week)day of any month of any year (The 4-digit years 1900-9999 are supported in Excel. 2-digit years are not covered.). It has three arguments: (week)day, month and year all entered as numbers. While developing it, I became over consumed with what the user could enter, so it became more of a study of Variant, IsMissing and some other methods of 'error handling'.

### The Code

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:    Returns the date of a last weekday of a month of a year.
' Inputs
'   dmlWeekDay:   Depending on the FirstDayOfWeek constant, it is the numeric
'                 presentation of a weekday e.g. if FirstDayOfWeek is 1 (for
'                 US, CA, JP), 1 is Sunday, 2 is Monday , 3 is Tuesday etc.
'   dmlMonth:     The numeric presentation of a month.
'   dmlYear:      A specified year.
'   FirstDayOfWeek as Constant:   This argument has been left as a constant
'                 on purpose, so it has to be changed directly in the code.
'                 For US or wherever the FDoW is Sunday, use 1. For EU or
'                 wherever the FDoW is Monday, use 2. For ME or wherever the
'                 FDoW is Saturday, use 7 etc.
' Returns:    A Date when dmlWeekday and dmlMonth are literally any number
'             or omitted and dmlYear is any positive or negative number from
'             1900-9999 or omitted. An empty string ("") otherwise.
'*******************************************************************************
Function DAYMONL(Optional ByVal dmlWeekDay, Optional ByVal dmlMonth, _
        Optional ByVal dmlYear)

    ' First Day of Week
    Const FirstDayOfWeek As Long = 1  ' 1 (Sunday), 2 (Monday), 7 (Saturday)

    Dim vntDay As Variant   ' Weekday "firstdayofweek" Parameter Array
    Dim dt As Date          ' 1st of Next Month

    DAYMONL = "" ' To return after Exit Function.

    ' Choose Weekday "firstdayofweek" Parameter Array.
    Select Case FirstDayOfWeek
        Case 1: vntDay = Array(7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)   ' Sunday:     US, CA, JP
        Case 2: vntDay = Array(6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)   ' Monday:     EU
        Case 7: vntDay = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)   ' Saturday:   ME
        'Case 3: vntDay = Array(5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4)   ' Tuesday:
        'Case 4: vntDay = Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3)   ' Wednesday:
        'Case 5: vntDay = Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2)   ' Thursday:
        'Case 6: vntDay = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1)   ' Friday:
        Case Else: MsgBox "Wrong FirstDayOfWeek parameter.": Exit Function
    End Select

    ' Weekday
    If IsMissing(dmlWeekDay) Then
        dmlWeekDay = WeekDay(Date)  ' Today('s (Week)Day)
      Else
        ' Ensure that dmlWeekDay is a number.
        If Not IsNumeric(dmlWeekDay) Then Exit Function
        ' Int ensures whole number.
        ' Abs ensures positive number.
        ' Mod ensures number from 1 to 7.
        dmlWeekDay = Abs(Int(dmlWeekDay)) Mod 7
        ' 0 is useless, 7 is needed.
        If dmlWeekDay = 0 Then dmlWeekDay = 7
        'dmlWeekDay = Int(dmlWeekDay)
        'If dmlWeekDay < 1 Or dmlWeekDay > 7 Then Exit Function
    End If

    ' Month
    If IsMissing(dmlMonth) Then
        dmlMonth = Month(Date)      ' Today's Month
      Else
        ' Ensure that dmlMonth is a number.
        If Not IsNumeric(dmlMonth) Then Exit Function
        ' Int ensures whole number.
        ' Abs ensures positive number.
        ' Mod ensures number from 1 to 12.
        dmlMonth = Abs(Int(dmlMonth)) Mod 12
        ' 0 is useless, 12 is needed.
        If dmlMonth = 0 Then dmlMonth = 12
        'dmlMonth = Int(dmlMonth)
        'If dmlMonth < 1 Or dmlMonth > 12 Then Exit Function
    End If

    ' Year
    If IsMissing(dmlYear) Then
        dmlYear = Year(Date)        ' Today's dmlYear
      Else
        ' Ensure that dmlYear is a number.
        If Not IsNumeric(dmlYear) Then Exit Function
        ' Int ensures whole number.
        ' Abs ensures positive number.
        dmlYear = Abs(Int(dmlYear))
        ' Ensure dmlYear is a number from 1900 to 9999.
        If dmlYear < 1900 Or dmlYear > 9999 Then Exit Function
        If dmlYear = 9999 And dmlMonth = 12 Then
            ' Excel doesn't support dates greater than 12/31/9999.
            ' The following "dmlMonth + 1" would produce an error.
            DAYMONL = DateSerial(9999, 12, 24 _
                    + Application.Match(dmlWeekDay, vntDay, 0))
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    ' Write the date of the 1st of next month to a variable.
    dt = DateSerial(dmlYear, dmlMonth + 1, 1)
    ' Subtract the match (position) of dmlWeekday in Weekday "firstdayofweek"
    ' Parameter Array from dt.
    DAYMONL = dt - WeekDay(dt, Application.Match(dmlWeekDay, vntDay, 0))

End Function
```

### Usage in Excel

**US**

To calculate the last Saturday in October of 2019:

```
=DAYMONL(7,10,2019)
```

To calculate the last Wednesday in April of 1999:

```
=DAYMONL(4,4,1999)
```

**EU**

To use the function with the first day of the week as **Monday**, you have to 'manually' change the `FirstDayOfWeek` constant to `2`. Then you can use the following formulas for the previous two examples:

```
=DAYMONL(6;10;2019)
=DAYMONL(3;4;1999)
```

Comment: Thanks, the requirement is to enter the year in a cell and the answer will be the last Saturday in October date. for example, when the input is 2019, the answer is 26/10/2019

Comment: @Elia: Cell **A1** contains **2019**. In e.g. cell **B1** use **=LSat10(A1)**.

Comment: Appreciate your kind answers, I only get number not a date

Comment: @Elia: It is showing the **Date Serial Number**. You have to format the cell as a date (Format>>Cells>>Date), then the value in the cell will show as a date.

Comment: That's great, thank you so much for your kind support

Comment: @VBasic2008 Is `Application.Volatile` really needed?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij: I obviously do not fully understand the concept of Volatile. I've read the Visual Basic Help about it several times but I've encountered scenarios (I think that I have) where it also wouldn't be needed, but the values wouldn't update correctly. Could you provide a link to an example where it is obviously mandatory. – VBasic2008 1 hour ago

Comment: Correct Approach +1). BTW you could even avoid the loop by this function return code: `LSat10 = vntDate - (Weekday(vntDate) Mod 7)`, where the modulo operator guarantees no change in date when vntDate is already a Saturday (as `7 Mod 7` equals 0).

Comment: @T.M.: Thanks for the tip. I figured it out after user11040196 uploaded his answer, but I didn't wanna cramp it. In the meanwhile I've done a function based on his answer for any Weekday, any Month and any Year for US or EU .. with some crazy error checking. Have to do some testing before I upload. Maybe will rather upload to CodeReview and provide a link.

Comment: @VBasic2008 if you need good reference on volatile functions then I will suggest Charles Williams' site link http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm . In this case, it is not needed. It would be needed if this function needed to calculate based on a range it is not directly referencing to.